# Display the connected customer information

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 tables which are `user` and `customer`, The first table has the following fields: `(id, name, email, password)`

Then, the table `customer` has the following fields: `(id, name, firstname)`.

In my Controller Customer, via my function index(), I have to retrieve `id_user` from my table `user`.

**Question 1:** Is my relationship correct between my 2 tables?

Model **Customer**

```
protected  $fillable = ['name', 'firstname', 'user_id'];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Model **User**

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Customer');
}
```

**Question 2:** How do I retrieve ID of the user who is connected ?

I have for now this only...

```
public function index()
{
    $customers = Customer::orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
    return view('customers.index', compact('customers'));
}
```

**Question 3:** I want to understand the two answers, but I would also like to understand how I can adapt my file index.blade.php via my loop, please.

```
@foreach($customers as $customer)
 <tr>
   <td> {{$customer->name}}</td>
    <td> {{$customer->firstname}}</td>
```

Thank you for your explanations.

Comment: What is foreign key in `customer` table?

Comment: @mare96: user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your models are good. If you want to return `user` relation for every `customer` you should try like this:

```
public function index()
{
        $customers = Customer::with('user')->orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
        return view('customers.index', compact('customers'));
}
```

And in your view you should have:

```
@foreach($customers as $customer)
 <tr>
   <td> {{$customer->name}}</td>
   <td> {{$customer->firstname}}</td>
   <td> {{$customer->user->id}}</td>
```

More about that [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Answer (score 0):

> **Question 1:** Is my relationship correct between my 2 tables?

Yes, your relationship is correct.

**Explanation:**

For your `customer` table, you indicate that a customer profile ***belongs to*** one and only one user. This is an inverse one-to-one entity relationship.

For your `user` table, you indicate that a user ***has one*** and only one customer profile. This is a one-to-one entity relationship.

> **Question 2:** How do I retrieve ID of the user who is connected?

Use Laravel's *Eager Loading* by calling the `with()` method to retrieve the customer data **with** the associated user data like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $customers = Customer::with('user')->orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
    return view('customers.index', compact('customers'));
}
```

**Explanation:**

The returned result can be visualized like this:

```
{Customer}
    |
    •id
    •name
    •firstname
    •{user}
        |
        • id
        • name
        • email
```

Finally you can get the results including the user ID in your view like this:

```
@foreach($customers as $customer)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $customer->user->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $customer->firstname }}</td>
        <td>{{ $customer->name }</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

For more details on Laravel Entity Relationships see the relevant [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships).